# Telegraf input plugin: How to determine form which service to take inputs

Tags: linux, apache, devops, grafana, telegraf

I'm trying to use the TICK stack. What I'm really confused even after reading so much in google is how to simply set up an input plugin to monitor for example my apache server or whatever remote server.

It may be a simple config but for me the telegraph.conf didn't really help.

In short:

How to point the apache server as a source for gathering metrics in telegraf.conf

How to be sure that metrics (input plugins) are somehow linked with the source
in telegraf.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [Input Plugins](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf#input-plugins) are for.
When you have a service running in your machine, all you need to do is, you need to tell telegraf to collect data from that service using `input` (given that Telegraf has a plugin for it).

Suppose for instance, I want to collect data from `postfix`, I will first check if there is already a plugin for telegraf that is capable of doing it. There is, in fact a telegraf plugin that can collect postfix data, [Postfix telegraf plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/postfix)

Now if I want to use this plugin, all I need to do is add `[[inputs.postfix]]` in `telegraf.conf` file and customize it using the options available on postfix plugin page.

Similarly, there is [Apache input plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/apache) as well which can be used simply by adding `[[inputs.apache]]` in `telegraf.conf` file and customizing options based on your requirements (given on plugin's page).